# mocking useReducer's store inside Jest/Enzyme without importing reducer

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I'm trying to write a test that involves updating the `useReducer` state for a component called `<Dashboard />`.

```
  const [store, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, dashboardStore);
```

Inside the test, I want to be able to update the `store`.

```
    const wrapper = mount(<Dashboard />); // <Dashboard /> contains the useReducer

    ...

    it('example test', () => {
      let mockStore = ['first item'];
      mockStore.push('second item');

      expect(wrapper.find(Dashboard).find('input').props().value.toBe('second item');
    });
```

In the example test, I have some pseudocode mocking `store` and then pushing a value to it. I then check to see if another child element within this component was updated based on the `store` change.

Is this possible? Will I need to import the `useReducer` into the test file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, if you refactor `Dashboard` to use dependency injection, providing the initial state of the store as a prop:

```
function Dashboard({dashboardStore}) {
    ...
    const [store, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, dashboardStore);
    ...
}
```

Then, you can provide the mock store as a prop in your test:

```
let mockStore = ['first item'];
mockStore.push('second item');
const wrapper = mount(<Dashboard dashboardStore={mockStore} />);
```

Otherwise, if that isn't possible, you're left with mocking `useReducer` in your test.